# how to fetch data from spring hibernate db batch by batch

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Say my query retrieves 30,000 records but I have to retrieve 3000 records in one batch.  Totally I have to retrieve 30,000 records in 10 batches. I'm using spring hibernate, how to do?

Comment: Object-relational mapping isn't optimal for batch operations. I recommend that you use JDBC for those operations.

Comment: what are you doing with the data after?

Answer (score 0):

Fetching data batch by batch using Spring and hibernate, refer below links :-

https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/

http://www.javamakeuse.com/2015/03/tutorial-hibernate-4-batch-fetching.html